# Is there a way to make the Displace modifier still?

Tags: modifiers

When i add the Displace Modifier to a 3D model, the animation of it continues endessly, how can i make it being still without having to press 'Apply' on the modifier bar?

Comment: Could you please clarify? Nothing should be moving unless you animated the mapping or the texture.

Comment: A screen shot of the modifier settings could help, or even better, a .blend file

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ If you use a 'Noise' texture for displacement it will animate automatically, though it's obviously not mentioned if they are using that.

Comment: I never had it do that, I think I always used the more controllable `Clouds` texture type though.

Comment: @RayMairlot Wow, I did not know that....